# angularJS filter date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a filter to filter out a date that is a string. The date I get from an API is

```
"/Date(1418716652000+0000)/"
```

I have a function which converts the date to the type I want:

```
1418716652000
```

The function is:

```
$scope.convertDate = function(published_first) {
    var date = (published_first.match(/\(.*\)/, ''));
    var convertedDate = date[0];
    date = eval(convertedDate.replace(/\//g,''));
    return date;
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id ="news" ng-repeat="new in news | filter:convertDate">
  <h3 class="title" ng-repeat="n in new">
  <span>{{n.title}}</span><br/>
  <div class="title-data">              
    <span ng-if="n.byline.length > 0">by: {{n.byline}}</span>
    <br/>
    <span>
    <span>published: {{n.published_first | date:'medium'}}</span><br/>
    </span>
</div>
```

I've been trying to run this as a filter in my HTML in the ng-repeat div, but it's not working. I've also tried running the filter in the same span which includes the angular date:'medium' filter. That doesn't work either. Can someone help with what I'm missing?

Comment: You need to create a filter. binding the function to the scope is not sufficient.

Comment: Don't use *eval*. To convert a String to Number, use `+(convertedDate.replace(/\//g,''))` or more semantically: `Number(convertedDate.replace(/\//g,''))`.

Comment: @RobG I tried Number(convertedDate.replace(/\//g,''))  , but I get: undefined NaN, NaN NaN:NaN:NaN

Comment: What value to you get from `convertedDate.replace(/\//g,'')`?

Comment: @RobG If i run the following i get: (1418394563000+0000)

    `date =  convertedDate.replace(/\//g,'')
    console.log(date);`

Comment: You should be able to use `date = +published_first.match(/\d+/)[0]`.

Comment: @RobG that one works. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a filter function like shown [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

```
module.filter('convertDate', function() {
  return function(published_first) {
    var date = (published_first.match(/\(.*\)/, ''));
    var convertedDate = date[0];
    date = eval(convertedDate.replace(/\//g,''));
    return date;
  };
})
```

2) Use your filter to format your date:

```
<div id ="news" ng-repeat="new in news">
  <h3 class="title" ng-repeat="n in new">
  <span>{{n.title}}</span><br/>
  <div class="title-data">              
    <span ng-if="n.byline.length > 0">by: {{n.byline}}</span>
    <br/>
    <span>
    <span>published: {{n.published_first | convertDate | date:'medium'}}</span><br/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the API you are using presents you with news object with a **published_first** property in a transport format that you want to present differently, but that data doesn't change at runtime after it is received.

Doing the conversion in markup as a filter or function within any kind of watch means you are constantly converting the date with every event that triggers a digest. It would be preferable to run the convertDate() function from the controller or service that receives the news items and do the conversion against each item as it is received from the API. Under this scenario the conversion from String to Date is done only once for each news item and your markup then becomes:

```
<span>published: {{n.published_first | date:'medium'}}</span>
```

Additionally, if you can be assured that the format coming from the API will always be consistent (which it should), you can one line to the conversion to a timestamp with:

```
$scope.convertDate = function(published_first) {
    return parseInt(published_first.substr(6), 10); 
}
```

The line removes the initial non-numeric characters for **/Date(** and parses up to the first non-numeric which will either be **+** or **)** depending on precision.

Answer (score 0):

avoid using filters if at all possible.  [Filters can cause huge performance issues in large applications.](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications#q72ZmcMU67C6Y1od.99)

That said, since you put the function on the scope, you can use it in markup:

```
<span>published: {{convertDate(n.published_first) | date:'medium'}}</span><br/>
```

Comment: Your link has nothing to do with the [formatting filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) that I suggested. It pertains to [subset selection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). @user3361996's application of filter was wrong to begin with.

Comment: I'm aware the implementation was wrong in the first place and that your filter implementation is correct.  My link pertains to the poor performance of filters, whether they be used for formatting or subset selection.  "Avoid using filters if at all possible. They are run twice per digest cycle, once when anything changes, and another time to collect further changes, and do not actually remove any part of the collection from memory, instead simply masking filtered items with css."

Comment: I don't read it this way: "...and do not actually remove any part of the collection from memory, instead simply masking filtered items with css" - this doesn't relate to formatting.

Comment: In any event, this whole performance consideration isn't worth discussing as it is very context specific and @user3361996 didn't specify the amount of items being rendered. So while it is an interesting side note, it may never actually be a problem for him/her. Making a blanket statement such as "avoid using filters if at all possible" without specifying the context in which this holds is highly dubious.

Comment: downvoting me when you don't understand that there is no difference in formatting filters vs "subset selection" filters when it comes to performance is highly dubious.  ["Filters can cause huge performance issues in large applications."](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications#q72ZmcMU67C6Y1od.99).  large applications.  that's context.  [here's more context for you](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=angular%20js%20filter%20peformance)

Comment: To the OP, if you're just interested in how filters work then the answer you accepted is accurate. However, @James-newell's answer is the best approach. scrub your JSON response data in an angular service, and map it to a client side model object that you control. Then bind to that model.